# Anybody heard of HOSTING 2.0

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

What is HOSTING 2.0 , what does it actually means? what is the difference between normal and 2.0 hosting?

Comment: Probably yet another marketing buzz word referring to cloud services.

Comment: You realise you'll never be able to un-hear any answer to this question? ;-)

Comment: http://www.webhostingresourcekit.com/262.html

Comment: I found this and many other links in google but I couldn't figure out the cache .. I came accross that word while I was looking for a hosting to buy for my web site , I saw it at MT(media temple) website the term web 2.0

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. It's just marketing fluff.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting 2.0 is supposed to be hosting services that support Web 2.0 technologies like Ajax, Mashups and social networking  APIs.

The truth is that every decent host provides support for the technologies under them. So unless you want to do something not so common (like Erlang web interfaces) you wont have a problem with 99% of the hosting services around.